# Python coding flaw for making acronyms

Tags: python

The code written below should give results like below. For example, if input is ' Lion head and Snake tail', output should be - 'LHAST'.

Instead the result is 'LLLLL'. Please check my code. If possible please suggest better practice and help me with better code.

Code is as follows:

```
#ask for Input
name = input('Input words to make acroname :')

#make all in caps
name = name.upper()

#turn them in list 
listname = name.split()

#cycle through
for namee in listname:
    #Get the first letter & type in same line
    print(name[0],end="")
print()

input (' press a key to move out' )
```

Comment: Welcome to [SO]! One thing you should know about our editor. When you [edit] a question, highlight a code snippet and click the `{}` button. That will format your code for maximum readability.

Comment: You meant `namee[0]`, not `name[0]`. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: thanks @Carcigenicate

Answer (score 1):

You may correct your code. Instead of `print(name[0])` you should use `print(namee[0])` as you want to print the first letter of the word, not the original name.

A good practice is to name the variables the more descriptive you can so as to avoid such typos.

If you want to print the acronym in same line I would suggest to use below code to get variable `acronym` with the desired output:

```
phrase = raw_input('Input words to make acronym:')
phrase = phrase.upper()
list_words = phrase.split()
acronym = [word[0] for word in list_words]
acronym = "".join(acronym)
print acronym
```

Comment: Or, in one line, `acronym = "".join(word[0] for word in phrase.split()).upper()`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `str.join` with a `generator-expression` for a one-line solution to the problem:

```
>>> name = "Lion head and Snake tail"
>>> ''.join(i[0].upper() for i in name.split())
'LHAST'
```

---

**why?**

Well if we start from inside the generator, we are iterating through `name.split()`. The `.split` method of a `str` returns a `list` of all the different `strings` which have been found by splitting on what is passed into the method. The default character is a space and since we want the words, this is fine for us.

We then say that for each word `i` in this `list`, take the first character from the string with: `i[0]`. We then convert this to upper case with `str.upper()`.

Then, the final step is to join all these characters together and that is done with the `str.join` method.

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
print ''.join([P[0] for P in input('Input words to make acroname :').upper().split()])
```

Use `input('')` for python 3 and `raw_input('')` for python 2